# osm2po "show option"

Tags: osm2po

The "show expansion" option in the web interface, how do i invoke that from the command line. I am trying something like this...with "debugExpansion=true"...

http://:8888/Osm2poService?cmd=fr&source=486477&target=0&findShortestPath=false&ignoreRestrictions=false&ignoreOneWays=false&routerClassId=0&heuristicFactor=0.0&maxCost=1.0&debugExpansion=true&key=Key&value=Value&format=geojson

When I run this, I get a "ERR.1 No route found" return value. I want to get the convex hull that shows up in the web interface.

Answer (score 1):

**cmd=fh** (findHull)

Example 1 (2km circle)

```
http://localhost:8888/Osm2poService?cmd=fh&source=11473&findShortestPath=true&maxCost=2.0&format=geojson
```

Example 2 (12 minutes circle)

```
http://localhost:8888/Osm2poService?cmd=fh&source=11473&findShortestPath=false&maxCost=0.2&format=geojson
```